# Перечисление подсписков списка

Tags: python, список

Как можно уйти от принудительного перечисления строк массива? (z[0],z[1],z[2])

```
import itertools

z = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['G H', 'I', 'F H']]
r = []
for x in itertools.product(z[0],z[1],z[2]):
    r.append(list(x))
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно "распаковать" список с помощью оператора `*`:

```py
for x in itertools.product(*z):
```